# read first 10MB from file using c#

Tags: c#, md5, filestream

I need to get the first 10mb of a file and compute md5 from this, how can i achieve this? I cant find any sample of reading piece of a file.
I've got something like this:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
file.Close();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
{
     sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
}
var md5Final = sb.ToString();
```

But it reads whole file.

Comment: _Off topic:_ I use `BitConverter.ToString(retVal).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();` instead of a `StringBuilder` and `for`-loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read the file in chunks and feed it to the MD5CryptoServiceProvider in chunks, using [`TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx). This way, you don't have to consume 10 MB of memory for the buffer. Example:

```
long read = 0;
int r = -1; 
const long bytesToRead = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
const int bufferSize = 10*1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
using(var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) )
{
    while(read <= bytesToRead && r != 0) 
    {
        read += (r = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize));
        md5.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, r, null, 0);
    }
}
md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0,0);
string md5Final = String.Join("", md5.Hash.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
```

Answer (score 3):

To read part of a file using small chunks, you can try:

```
public byte[] ReadPart(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read=0;

    int chunk;
    while ( (chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length-read)) > 0)
    {
        read += chunk;
        if (read == buffer.Length && read < 10*1024*1024) // 10MB
        {
            int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
            if (nextByte==-1)
            {
                return buffer;
            }

            byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length*2];
            Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
            newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
            buffer = newBuffer;
            read++;
        }
    }
    // Buffer is now too big. Shrink it.
    byte[] ret = new byte[read];
    Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
    return ret;
}
```

and then compute MD5 on this array...

Comment: But this will allocate a 10 MB array on the Large Object Heap, which is not needed.

Comment: @driis: yes, you're right and I've already given you +1 for your answer :) Anyway, my answer could be general to read part of a file ;)

Comment: Would you care explaining the purpose of all this compared to reading the whole 10MB chunk in one `Read` call. TIA.

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator: there are a lot of situations for which is better to read file in small chunks; one could be the need to update UI while getting file (that could be remote or on a segmented and slow network). Another one could be when you need to retry the download of a chunk if it failed...

Answer (score 3):

```
  var bytes = new byte[10000000]; // Or 10*1024*1024 according to your def of a MB
  int realLength;

  using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
  {
    realLength = file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    // The file may be shorter than expected.
  }

  var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes, 0, realLength);
```

I have to admit though that allocating 10MB might not be the most elegant solution. I wrote it with 10KB instead of 10MB in mind. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first 10Mb into a byte[] and then give ComputeHash an instance of a MemoryStream, backed by the byte[].

Comment: `MemoryStream` is not needed, use `public byte[] HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byte[] buffer)`

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `Stream` class which limits the length of an underlying `Stream` object *(the `FileStream` in your case)*:

```
public class LengthLimitedStream : Stream
{
    private Stream baseStream;
    private long maxLength;

    public LengthLimitedStream(Stream stream, long maxLength)
    {
        if (stream.Position > maxLength) { throw new IOException(); }

        this.baseStream = stream;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return this.baseStream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return Math.Min(this.maxLength, this.baseStream.Length); }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.baseStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > maxLength)
            {
                throw new IOException();
            }

            this.baseStream.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (this.Position + offset + count > this.maxLength)
        {
            count = (int)(this.maxLength - (this.Position + offset));
        }

        return this.baseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    // Lots of stuff omitted you may want to implement but not important in this case ...
}
```

*(Add parameter validation and such things, but you'll get the idea)*

**This way you could still use the `ComputeHash(Stream)` method and it looks clean and simple *(in my opinion)*.**

Answer (score -1):

What about converting the file to a byte array , so you can loop over the the first 10MB.
TO get the byte array =>

```
private byte [] StreamFile(string filename)
{ 
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read); 

// Create a byte array of file stream length 
 byte[] fileData = new byte[fs.Length]; 

//Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array 
fs.Read(fileData,0,System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)); 

//Close the File Stream 
fs.Close(); 

return fileData; //return the byte data
}
```

After this i would just loop over fileData, and take the 10 first MB and do the MD5

Comment: change the fs.length to the 10 mb then

Comment: Better, but still allocates way more memory than is needed. And a single Read call might not give you the full 10 MB, from MSDN: "An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx

Comment: True, it's a general approach, not the most efficient one. But the question was how to do this, not the most efficient one. But your answer is more efficient